# Control popover location anchor for SelectField

Tags: material-ui

Does anyone know how to control the location of the popover of SelectField?

I know that selectfield holds a dropdown menu in it and doesn't contain a popover but thought that maybe it's possible to control this somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually faced the same issue.

I don't think it's possible, at least it's not part of configurable properties. I looked at SelectField source, and apparently, even though `SelectField` is using `DropDownMenu` underneath, and `DropDown` is using `PopOver` underneath, but the configuration of `anchorOrigin` is hardcoded.

https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/DropDownMenu/DropDownMenu.js#L9

```
const anchorOrigin = {
  vertical: 'top',
  horizontal: 'left',
};
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible indeed:

```
<SelectField dropDownMenuProps={{anchorOrigin:{vertical:"center",horizontal:"left"}}}>
    <MenuItem value={1} primaryText="one" />
    <MenuItem value={2} primaryText="two" />
    <MenuItem value={3} primaryText="three" />
</SelectField>
```

If you need to exactly set up the positioning of your "popover" (which is actually a "dropdown menu"), I reckon you can try by overriding one of the different (style?) props of that menu: http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/dropdown-menu ("Properties" part)

An other way would be to use a popover instead...

Also, the new v1.0 beta just had its select component released ; it might give you a better control:
https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/demos/selects/

Answer (score 2):

Here's how it can be done in material-ui v4.11.3 (early 2021):

```
<Select
  value={10}
  MenuProps={{
    anchorOrigin: {
      vertical: "top",
      horizontal: "left",
    },
    transformOrigin: {
      vertical: "bottom",
      horizontal: "left",
    },
    getContentAnchorEl: null,
  }}
>
  <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

The `getContentAnchorEl: null` prop basically positions the rendered `Popover` such that it sticks to the `Select` component and does not stray away.

Answer (score 0):

You can over ride the dropdown menu's props by using the prop `dropDownMenuProps` in your `SelectField` component.